# Compilation error when testing non blocking Redis client (Fyrie) on Play Framework 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, akka, playframework-2.1

when I try to compile the following code

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
import net.fyrie.redis.RedisClient
import net.fyrie.redis.RedisClientConfig
//import akka.dispatch._
//import akka.dispatch.Future

object Application extends Controller {

  //  val rd: RedisClient = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379, new RedisClientConfig(1, true, true, 50 to 100))(akka.actor.ActorSystem.create)
  val rd = RedisClient.apply("localhost", 6379, new RedisClientConfig(1, true, true, 50 to 100))(akka.actor.ActorSystem.create)

  def nonblocktest(application: String, platform: String) = Action {
    val future: akka.dispatch.Future[Option[akka.util.ByteString]] = rd.get(StringBuilder.newBuilder.append(application).append('-').append(platform).toString)
    future onSuccess {
      case x => Ok(x.get.toString)
    } onFailure {
      case t: Throwable => Results.NoContent
    }
    Results.NoContent
  }

}
```

I get the following error

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[package dispatch contains object and package with same name: japi
one of them needs to be removed from classpath]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:346) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

I get the same if I uncomment any of the last two imports. I am trying to use fyrie for scala 2.10.0 in play framework 2.1.0. My goal is to test fyrie non blocking async calls performances against sedis (blocking). So what am I doing wrong? Knowing myself it could be something very (VERY) dumb.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of fyrie are you actually using? The original repo seams to be dead (last commit 1 year ago with dev versions of scala 2.10 and akka 2.0). If you use this version, it is probably due to the different versions of akka that play and fyrie use.

Comment: I am using the fyrie-redis_2.10.0-M1 I found in the snapshot repository. Do you know of anyother I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try to use [this fork](https://github.com/trafficland/fyrie-redis/tree/akka2.1) of fyrie redis, as the main repo seems to be dead and is using old dev versions of scala and akka.