# Writing to Rabbitmq with Scala

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to figure out how to send amqp messages in scala. I've found several libraries, but either they're [old](https://github.com/akka/akka-modules/blob/releasing-1.3.1/akka-amqp/src/main/scala/akka/amqp/ExampleSession.scala) or [blowing up](https://github.com/sstone/amqp-client/blob/scala2.10/src/main/scala/com/github.sstone/amqp/samples/Producer.scala) the compiler (no, not my code, the compiler - [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144747/compilation-error-when-testing-non-blocking-redis-client-fyrie-on-play-framewo)). Am I just supposed to roll my own and send the binary data, or what? I'm hesitant to try the old ones due to the dependency hell that I keep finding myself in.

Comment: Don't know what do you mean by blowing up the compiler, anyway we have been using the amqp-client library with success for quite some time in a big project (we did modify something because of the `IProcessor` approach).

Comment: The error that I'm getting is in the "similar" link. The error is `sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[package dispatch contains object and package with same name: japi`. Is there a blog post or something about how you guys got it working?

Comment: I've never seen this error before, it all worked fine from the start, are you sure the error is not deriving from your files or other dependencies?

Comment: That's possible. As a sanity check for me, what versions are you using (scala, sbt, akka, client-lib, etc.)?

Comment: On Scala 2.11.4, sbt 0.13.7, akka 2.3.6; on Scala 2.10.4, sbt 0.13.7, akka 2.3.2 and for the library on both 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Play Framework with https://github.com/sstone/amqp-client, pay attention about the correct version for your environment. Your must to use the correct version for Scala and Akka. I am using scala 2.11 with Akka 2.3.2+

Best regards